# WP-Paginate with custom query

Tags: wordpress

I'm using a custom query to retrieve only posts published in the last 30 days for a custom post type.

I have wp-paginate installed and am using it for pagination. The page itself is working fine, but wp-paginate seems to be showing enough pages for all posts, whether they were returned or not but the custom query.

For example, there are 35 published posts, but only 12 of them in the last 30 days. WP-Paginate should only display 2 pages for all 12 posts in the last 30 days, but it's showing 4 pages, with page 3 and 4 being blank.

My code for the query is:

```
<?php 

$current_page = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

function filter_where($where = '') {
    $where .= " AND post_date > '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-30 days')) . "'";
    return $where;
}

$jobPosts = null;
add_filter('posts_where', 'filter_where');
$jobPosts = new WP_Query('post_type=job_boards&paged=' . $current_page);
remove_filter('posts_where', 'filter_where');

while ($jobPosts -> have_posts()) : $jobPosts -> the_post();

    // Display stuff

endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();

if (function_exists('wp_paginate')) wp_paginate();

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I seem to have solved it, though it's way more complicated than I think it needs to be. I'm passing the number of pages and the current page to display into the wp_paginate function:

```
wp_paginate(array('pages' => $num_pages, 'page' => $current_page));
```

Comment: nice dude, if there's other people searching around, this works. To get the current page use the code Phil posted above, and for $num_pages use $wp_query->max_num_pages

Answer (score 1):

While using custom query try below

**For wp pagenavi plugin**

```
if (function_exists('wp_pagenavi')):

 wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $jobPosts ) );

endif;
```

**For wp paginate plugin**

```
if (function_exists('wp_paginate')):
   wp_paginate(false,$jobPosts);
endif;
```

Comment: I still get 4 page numbers listed with 2 pages (3 and 4) being blank.